# Doubling the area of a triangle in spherical geometry

Tags: area, spherical-geometry

I've been given this prompt to work on;

Show that in spherical geometry, there exists a triangle whose area is twice that of a given right triangle.

I don't know how to find the area of a triangle in spherical geometry and it is not something expected for this question. I'm pretty sure the prompt is true and there is a way to show it is true but I'm struggling to get past the thought that a sphere is a finite space. A sphere has a measurable size. I'm fairly certain my thought is wrong but I don't know where to start with showing the prompt is true.

Comment: Ummmm... Why not just start with a small triangle and increase its sides until it is very large?  The continuous area function must, then, equal the required area at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the triangle is *right*, we can place the right-angled vertex at the north pole and have two sides concurring with (parts of) meridians. Then reflecting the triangle across either leg and joining it to the original copy will naturally produce a spherical triangle of twice the area.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. But what happens if you keep reflecting and doubling and eventually reach the other leg you haven't reflected across? Can you keep going and overlap what you already have?

Comment: @JbkPanda You can reflect only at most twice, after which there is the possibility of overlaps.

Comment: Thank you for the help!